# ARM motherboard

Tags: motherboard, gigabit-ethernet, arm

Does anyone know a motherboard for an ARM-compatible CPU, with Gigabit Ethernet? I took a look at Beagleboard (which is actually more than just a motherboard) and some others, but I could only find 10/100 MBit Ethernet.

Comment: So motherboard questions are not hardware related. How interesting...

Comment: Probably closed because it sounds too much like a shopping recommendation.

Comment: It would be if ARM motherboard were so widespread that I just had to choose one. Actually, it's tricky to just find one...

Answer (score 1):

I have the TS-7800, which does have gigabit ethernet: http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=ts-7800

However, they forked the Linux kernel for this board. The vanilla kernel works, but with some limitations, see http://www.digriz.org.uk/ts78xx/kernel

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to mod a NAS enclosure such as synology or lacie. I believe there are modding/hacking forums out there for these. Both companies ship arm based gigabit ethernet systems.

Or consider arduino, there is now a 96Mhz (Megahertz, enough for many apps) board. There may be an addon for this. O'Reilly books have some good guides on arduino and embedded systems as well.

Comment: Actually, the purpose is a parallel-computing experiment, so I would like to link several boards, each with some computing power. An Arduino will not do the job.